# Structure Size Optimization

Tags: c, structure

I have a system that can run either 32 or 64 bit. If I define a structure with 7 longs and 1 char, then I understand that if the structure runs on 32 bits, a long will be assigned 32 bits, a char will be assigned 8 bits and the structure will require at least 232 bits. But if the structure runs on 64 bits, then a long will be assigned 64 bits, a char will be assigned 8 bits and the structure will require at least 456 bits. I also understand that the memory will be optimized for arrays of a structure if the structure requires a power of 2 bits. This structure, then, will have to fill 256 bits on a 32 bit system or 512 bits on a 64 bit system. Will that padding be automatically added to the structure to optimize the memory, or should I add something to the structure to bring it closer to a power of 2 bits in order to optimize the processing of an array of those structures?

Comment: it is not 'a power of 2 bits'  rather it is a multiple of the largest object/field within the struct.  so if the largest field within the struct is an int of 4 bytes, then the max number of fill bytes will be 3

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** Just saw the article about array indexing using shifts vs multiplication. My advice would be to size the structs appropriately for your data, taking care not to waste space due to slop if you can help it. If a profiler determines that *indexing elements* is the major performance hit for you, you can try *adding slop* to specifically reach a specific byte size. However, my intuition tells me (on a modern system with caches), you'll *suffer a bigger performance hit by needlessly increasing the size of your structures and pushing useful memory out of cache!* :D

(Original response follows)

I don't think you'll see a performance penalty from not having your structure *sized* to a power of two. The performance issue with arrays of structs is typically due to *alignment*.

**Alignment and Performance**

In order to minimize the number of instructions required to access a scalar variable, the variable has to exist at a location in memory that is a *multiple of its size in bytes*. The implication for structures is as follows:

1. Practically speaking, since the address of a struct is equal to the address of its first member, the beginning address of a given struct has to be a multiple of the size of its first member, in bytes
2. For compiler writers, the *pragmatic* approach is to align structures to a multiple of the widest scalar value they contain
3. *Arrays of structs are allocated with padding between them to guarantee that these alignment guarantees hold over the entire array* - **most** compilers will do this for you! :)
4. Padding is also added between variables in the struct, if necessary to ensure that all structure members are properly aligned

**Dealing with Structure Alignment**

*Most compilers on modern systems will automatically add padding after the structure in order to satisfy alignment requirements for self-aligned types.*

So, in general, your structure will be aligned to a multiple of the *largest element* in the structure. As a result of the longs in your struct, each struct in an array will be spaced such that the beginning address of each is a multiple of `sizeof(long)`. This is accomplished by transparently adding "slop" to the end of your struct. Try this and see what you get:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct my_struct
{
    long l1;
    long l2;
    long l3;
    long l4;
    long l5;
    long l6;
    long l7;
    char c;
};

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    printf("sizeof(my_struct) == %lu\n", sizeof(struct my_struct));
    return 0;
};

/* EOF */
```

**A Note on Packing:**

In general, for self-aligned types on systems which support them you can *usually* use `__attribute__((packed))` but this will likely result in a *performance penalty* as the number of machine instructions required to access a given member will be increased.

If you *really* care about not wasting space due to alignment slop and you don't need the full range of values in one of those longs, see if you can move that `char` into one of the longs with a mask or try using bitfields.

One of my personal favorite resources on structure packing and alignment: [The Lost Art of C Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)

Answer (score 0):

> Will that padding be automatically added to the structure to optimize
>   the memory, or should I add something to the structure to bring it
>   closer to a power of 2 bits in order to optimize the processing of an
>   array of those structures?

No, you don't need to add anything to your struct declaration. Generally speaking alignment and padding is taken care of by the compiler.
You can test that yourself by printing the output of `sizeof(your_struct);`.

It is however possible to do the opposite and optimize for size instead of speed. This can be useful is memory is scare or if you send your raw struct over the network. GCC has `__attribute__((packed))` to do this.

Comment: Along with the directives `#pragma pack(push)` and `#pragma pack(pop)`.

Comment: Note that while your answer is correct for this case, it wouldn't be if OP had 5 longs and one char, since what op requires is *power of 2 bits*, but a compiler in most x64 systems would align the struct for long and have 7 padding bytes, not 23, as requested by OP.

Comment: @holgac Indeed good catch. Though I suppose OP wanted optimized alignment/padding rather than power of 2.

Comment: What I understand is that the power of 2 measure optimizes the processing of operations on arrays of the structures, which is different than, but involves, optimizing the alignment/padding?

Comment: So it sounds like I have to do my own padding/alignment to meet the power of 2 optimization, which will be different for 32bit or 64bit.

Comment: But if I put the char first, then the unpacked structure will be 8 longs, which is a power of 2 in either 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: Oh I see. I am not sure about this. I would assume that with instruction reordering the more you can fit in a cache line the better. Maybe the CPU could start working on data from `struct N + 1` that would sit in the extra free byte from `struct N` data. Don't take my word for it tho. As @holgac said, in your case it would aligned to a power of 2.

Comment: @MarkLeavenworth can you provide a resource that recommends power of 2 sized structures? I've only heard of alignment benefits, that some architectures prevent fetching/storing unaligned data, and those that allow usually do it poorly. But I haven't heard of this power of 2 thing.

Comment: https://www.eventhelix.com/RealtimeMantra/basics/OptimizingCAndCPPCode.htm#Adjust%20Structure%20Sizes%20to%20Power%20of%20Two

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit late, but I just want to share this article about structure packing with details on how to optimize the size of the struct variables with rearrangement of the order of declaration of the struct members:
http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/